# How can I execute a package with a package password in SSIS through code?

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to call an SSIS package through C# code. The package worked before I put a package password on, but now I'm trying to supply the password I'm getting an error that the password is wrong or not supplied.

```
                Package package = app.LoadPackage("mypackage.dtsx, null);
            package.PackagePassword = "mypass";

            DTSExecResult result = package.Execute();
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you need:

```
app.PackagePassword = "mypass";
```

Answer (score 3):

You must set your password before load your package, try this:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
app.PackagePassword = "mypass";
Package package = app.LoadPackage("mypackage.dtsx, null");
```

This will work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
app.PackagePassword = "mypass";
Package package = app.LoadPackage("mypackage.dtsx, null);
```